# docker registry behind two proxies

Tags: docker

I have the following setup:

nginx proxy1{https} -> nginx proxy2{https} on some other machine -> docker registry.

I have tried running few docker commands like login and push/pull etc.

docker login command is working fine.

docker push command is not working as expected(getting 400 error)

These are the logs at ngnix1.

> "PATCH /v2/library/nginx_alpine/blobs/uploads/796ac2aa-299d-414f-a3b6-e81bfc3e3e0c?_state=P0FQyDvs3vbxP8hwIVtC9CA_o1TqOYhyGxOSW_0Zsp17Ik5hbWUiOiJsaWJyYXJ5L25naW54X2FscGluZSIsIlVVSUQiOiI3OTZhYzJhYS0yOTlkLTQxNGYtYTNiNi1lODFiZmMzZTNlMGMiLCJPZmZzZXQiOjAsIlN0YXJ0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMTgtMDYtMDdUMjM6NDM6MDcuOTgwMDMzNTM4WiJ9 HTTP/1.1" 400 271 "-" "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(darwin\x5C))" "-"

all the GET, POST and HEAD calls seems to be working fine. However, PATCH request is throwing up 400 always at nginx1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently these are some issues with Docker. Here are some workarounds that helped me.

https://github.com/vmware/harbor/issues/3114

https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2225